# Can I transfer saved game data from one Windows phone to another?

Tags: windows-phone

I'm about to upgrade my Windows phone.  Is there any way to transfer saved game data from one Windows phone to another or will I have to start from scratch for all of my games?

Edit: Obviously, some games save some data to an external server or cloud.  I'm not talking about those games, I'm talking about the ones which have data saved locally on the phone.